# Python Dataframe find closest matching value with a tolerance

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame consisting of lists as elements. I want to find the closest matching values within a percentage of a given value.
My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[4,5,6]]})
df
           A
0     [1, 2]
1  [3, 5, 7]

# in each row, lets find a the values and their index that match 5 with 20% tolerance 
val = 5
tol = 0.2 # find values matching 5 or 20% within 5 (4 or 6)
df['Matching_index'] = (df['A'].map(np.array)-val).map(abs).map(np.argmin)
```

Present solution:

```
df
           A     Matching_index
0     [1, 2]     1                # 2 matches closely with 5 but this is wrong
1  [4, 5, 6]     1                # 5 matches with 5, correct.
```

Expected solution:

```
df
           A     Matching_index
0     [1, 2]     NaN              # No matching value, hence NaN
1  [4, 5, 6]     1                # 5 matches with 5, correct.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is get difference with `val` and then replace to missing values if not match tolerance, last get `np.nanargmin` which raise error if all missing values, so added next condition with `np.any`:

```
def f(x):
    a = np.abs(np.array(x)-val)
    m = a <= val * tol
    return np.nanargmin(np.where(m, a, np.nan)) if m.any() else np.nan
    
df['Matching_index']  = df['A'].map(f)

print (df)
           A  Matching_index
0     [1, 2]             NaN
1  [4, 5, 6]             1.0
```

Pandas solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].tolist(), index=df.index).sub(val).abs()

df['Matching_index'] = df1.where(df1 <= val * tol).dropna(how='all').idxmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: is this `np.argmax(a)` should be `np.argmin(a)`? I am curious

Comment: @Mainland - solution was changed, first was incorrect.

Comment: The `pandas` solution gave correct answers to my original data frame. This seemed more appropriate and a python way of doing it. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mainland - agree, you re correct ;)

Comment: I just posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122215/python-dataframe-map-indexes-to-a-column-of-lists-for-extracting-elements

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it you want all indexes or just a counter.

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[4,5,6,7,8]]})

val = 5
tol = 0.3

def closest(arr,val,tol):
    idxs = [ idx for idx,el in enumerate(arr) if (np.abs(el - val) < val*tol)]
    result = len(idxs) if len(idxs) != 0 else np.nan
    return result

df['Matching_index'] = df['A'].apply(closest, args=(val,tol,))
df
```

If you want all the indexes, just return `idxs` instead of `len(idxs)`.